# Is there error to run ionic serve error: failed to clean to directory Eperm : operation not permitted in www\build\15.js

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

{ Error: Failed to clean directory F:\projectname\www\build - EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat ‘F:\projectname\www\build\15.js’
at new BuildError (F:\IndiansInCA\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
at F:\IndiansInCA\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\clean.js:15:32
at new Promise ()
at Object.clean (F:\IndiansInCA\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\clean.js:7:12)
at buildProject (F:\IndiansInCA\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:99:13)
at F:\IndiansInCA\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:89:42
at step (F:\IndiansInCA\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:32:23)
at Object.next (F:\IndiansInCA\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:13:53)
at fulfilled (F:\IndiansInCA\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:4:58)
at hasBeenLogged: false, isFatal: false }

please provide me solution for this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

npm install -g cordova ionic is solution.